# Postgres db replication not shown in real time

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have been able to make a PostgreSQL replication between two of my local computers, by modifying the files `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` of both computers.

Then, in the first computer, there is a database that is being filled automatically, and we can see it being shown in real time. And in the second computer, there is the replicated database linked to it, but we can't see its updates in real time.

My problem is that the database is really changing, so the replication works, but it is not being shown in real-time.

When I use in `psql` the command

```
select * from pg_stat_replication;
```

I see my replication there, so I suppose that the publication and the subscription worked. But in the info that this command shows, in the part of `sync_state`, it shows `async`. Maybe I should change it to `sync` to make it work in real time (still do not know how, I'm checking if "alter publication", or "alter subscription"... not sure yet)?

Comment: It looks like you are using logical replication.  How are you changing the primary database?  When you change it, are you committing the transaction?

Comment: Exactly, we are using logical replication. The primary database is changing automatically from another program. I think this transaction is commited, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For synchronous logical replication, and if you want the changes to be visible on the standby immediately, set `synchronous_commit` to `remote_apply` and add the name of the subscription to `synchronous_standby_names` (both settings on the primary).

Both parameters have to be set in `postgresql.conf` on the primary (master) server. Don't forget to reload to activate the changes.

With synchronous replication you always have decreased availability of the whole system unless you have at least two standby servers.

Comment: Hmmm, I did not know that. I was trying to use this: "ALTER SUBSCRIPTION bsub2 SET (synchronous_commit = local);", as I saw here:
-https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altersubscription.html
-https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createsubscription.html

So you think that if instead "local" I put "remote_apply" it could work? Or should I also change from logical replication to physical replication?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems I was too rash in denying synchronous logical replication, thanks for the pointer. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)
I have already changed in the replicated database (not the replicator db as you said) the parameter "synchronous_commit" with the ALTER SUBSCRIPTION command, to "remote_apply" as you said (I was not able to do this from the primary database).
Now, I am looking how to change "synchronous_standby_names". I have seen that it is in the "postgres.conf" file, so I think I will directly put = "bsub2" (the name of the subscription), as you said to me, and also again in the replicated database (not the replicator, even if I am able to change it in the primary db)

Comment: Both settings have to be on the primary (replicated) server. Tell me if you meet problems, I have never tried that myself.

Comment: I can't change the "synchronous_commit" to "remote_apply" because I do not have acces to it from the "ALTER SUBSCRIPTION" command in the primary computer (that's why I made it in the second one). It tells me that this subscription does not exist. The only computer that recognizes this subscription and allow to use the command, is the secondary computer (the replicated database).

Regarding the "synchronous_standby_names", I can change it in both pcs, because I have access to the "postgres.conf" doc

Comment: You should change both settings in `postgresql.conf` on the primary. I'll have a look tomorrow and test it.

Comment: I have tested it today, and it works just as expected. Don't set any parameters in the subscription, simply edit `postgresql.conf` on the primary server and set the two parameters I have indicated in my answer.